# How to get the same MD5 with Delphi and PHP?

Tags: php, delphi, md5, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I'm using Delphi **XE2** with FireMonkey.

I have read many other questions about MD5 but didn't find an answer to the issue I have...
I've also tested different scripts to generate a MD5 from Delphi:

```
function MD5(const text: string) : string;
var
  md5 : TIdHashMessageDigest5;
begin
  md5    := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
  Result := LowerCase(md5.HashStringAsHex(text, TEncoding.ANSI));
  md5.Free;
end;
```

or

```
function MD5(const text: String) : string;
var
  md5: IMD5;
begin
  md5:= GetMD5;
  md5.Init;
  md5.Update(TByteDynArray(RawByteString(AnsiString(text))), Length(AnsiString(text)));
  Result := LowerCase(md5.AsString);
end;
```

Both give me the same results... which is **often** the same I have within PHP:

```
$md5 = md5($toencode);
$md5 = hash("md5", $toencode);
```

But the results are different if I use Delphi or PHP, when I request the MD5 of one of these chars: `"` or `'` 
There are maybe others chars which generate different results but I just find these ones during my tests...

I have tested with many **extended ASCII characters** and have the same MD5...

So, I don't understand why I have differences with few of them (`"` or `'` ), and I'd like to know if there's a way to always generate the PHP MD5 result from Delphi, whatever the chars are.

Any idea?

> For instance:
>
> with **Delphi**:
>
> ": b15835f133ff2e27c7cb28117bfae8f4
>
> ': 3590cb8af0bbb9e78c343b52b93773c9
>
> with **PHP**:
>
> ": 3bd864034f446da13581129bb17f9191
>
> ': 024c94d6e03b6f67a86b952b914816c7

Formalizing this question.. I've find the answer... BTW, I post it as others may have the same issue...

`"` and `'` are escaped in PHP... so, within Delphi, I have to encode `\"` and `\'`... if you think I have forgotten chars or if you want to add some details, do not hesitate...

Comment: You can probably run stripslashes in PHP before MD5ing

Comment: Yes... but.. ;o) I'm accessing a remote server where I don't have access to the code...

Comment: PHP escapes quote, double quote, backslash and 'NUL' (which is `#0` in Delphi I guess), see http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php

Comment: You do not calculate hashes on strings, but on binary data. Now go sit somewhere, and write that down 100 times.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers: I agree with you... but when an API demands a MD5 password... to use the API... you need to do some compromise ;)

Comment: Then you must make sure the password is encoded the same binary way at both sides. That's the crux of your problem. The only relevance of MD5 here is that it shows you got your encoding wrong. In this case: because you were escaping things that should not have been.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP `hash` function implements MD5 perfectly well.

The following PHP:

```
$md5 = hash("md5", "\"");
echo "\":&nbsp;&nbsp;", $md5, "<br/>";
$md5 = hash("md5", "'");
echo "':&nbsp;&nbsp;", $md5, "<br/>";
$md5 = hash("md5", "\\\"");
echo "\\\": ", $md5, "<br/>";
$md5 = hash("md5", "\\'");
echo "\\': ", $md5, "<br/>";
```

results in this output:

```
":  b15835f133ff2e27c7cb28117bfae8f4
':  3590cb8af0bbb9e78c343b52b93773c9
\": 3bd864034f446da13581129bb17f9191
\': 024c94d6e03b6f67a86b952b914816c7
```

So, the top two values are what you get from your Delphi code, and the same values that Ignacio obtained from Python. So, there's absolutely no reason to believe that the PHP MD5 code is at fault. And the bottom two values are what your PHP code is returning.

Which leaves us to conclude that you are feeding your Delphi code different input from that which you feed to your PHP code. If you feed them both the same input, you will get the same output.

Comment: Yes.. My bad... @StijnSanders's URL explained me the reason... My tests were wrong cause the variables which were filled from a `form`were _corrupted_ ([escaped with a backslash automatically](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php)).

Answer (score 6):

Delphi is in the right here.

```
>>> hashlib.md5('"').hexdigest()
'b15835f133ff2e27c7cb28117bfae8f4'
>>> hashlib.md5("'").hexdigest()
'3590cb8af0bbb9e78c343b52b93773c9'
```

PHP should not need those characters escaped by default; make sure that it is configured to not do so.

Comment: @David: I'm sure. Which is why I suspect that the characters are being needlessly "escaped".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It's a pretty strange escaping in fact. Not URL escaping as I would have guessed.

Answer (score 1):

```
    uses IdHashMessageDigest;

    function MD5(const texto:string):string;
    var
      idmd5 : TIdHashMessageDigest5;
    begin
      idmd5 := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
      try
        result := idmd5.HashStringAsHex(UTF8Encode(texto));
      finally
        idmd5.Free;
      end;
    end;
```

To exactly identical use `LowerCase(MD5('1234'));` this is identical with PHP MD5.